# the_post() conflict in wordpress script

Tags: wordpress

I have a code similar like this:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

 .... more code ...

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);  
if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
$my_query->the_post();

 .... other code ..
```

The question is how to avoid the conflict for `the_post()` ?
Because with first `while loop` I'm accessing some `posts` and with second while other posts. And my website display the info from second while, but it should display the info of posts from first while. I think now it is confusing posts...

Comment: if you want to show data from first while why you are using second while loop, anyways do not use the_post() in inner while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `wp_reset_query()` function

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

.... more code ...
wp_reset_query();
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);  
if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
$my_query->the_post();

.... other code ..
```

Here is the reference manual [wp_reset_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)

Comment: wp_reset_query() worked perfectly, but i have inserted it after the code, and now it is not conflicting, thank you!